# Release.Keystore for Map API

Tags: android, google-maps

I have run the following command to get `SHA1` key, and use it in the `Google Map API` to generate`API` Key.

However, when I use release version of the `APK`, the application does not show the map

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

I dont see `release.keystore` in the `%USERPROFILE%\.android` directory

[image]

Answer (score 0):

this command is just for your debug keystore, you need to do the same thing with your release Keystore

Comment: the same just change the path to your keystore path and  change the alias and pass

Comment: see my update, there is no `release.keystore` in the `android` folder.

Comment: release keystore is not in android folder, its a keystore you create to sign your app, for more information and how to create it check here https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html

Comment: sorry , you can try now